# Why do I get this waveform at the output after power down of Buck Converter

Tags: buck, converter

I am having a buck converter which steps down 8-16V input to 5V output. Load current = 0.6A
But upon removing the input power, I get the attached waveform.

My schematic circuit is similar to the one [in this datasheet's application diagram](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54260.pdf) on page 29.

Please let me know why I get this waveform upon removing the input voltage instantly?
[image: This is the waveform]

[image: This is my schematic]

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome, it would be better if you included your schematic as an image instead of a link.

Comment: thank you. added it

Comment: @Newbie If possible, please also remove these yellow and blue dashed squares. They don't improve readability. Could you also add the part that got cut off left of TP103?

Comment: The parts to the left of TP103 are just a few input decoupling capacitors and the input voltage

Comment: What is it that concerns you about the resulting waveform?

Comment: Why does the output not go to 0V the instant the input voltage is turned to 0V? We can see from the waveform that the output is gradually decreasing and suddenly peaks and then gradually decreases and peaks till it reaches 0V? Why the sudden peaks?

Comment: Not the issue here, but why do you squeeze down a 5 V DC output into 5 V/div scale on your scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- when DC In is removed, the bulk storage cap is the reservoir to attempt to boost the decaying output. Your use of PG is unclear for Reset and this ought to be used to disable EN as per your requirements, which are TBD.
- it is a form of quasi-relaxation oscillations decaying from bulk input cap.

Comment: But why does it boost the output voltage?

Comment: Hi-side Nch gets a boost pulse when Hi-side s off and Lo-side conducts with PWM

Comment: Show other pins on scope if you really want to understand. Walk around all the pins.  !!!   OK , explore, figure out from internal block diagram and descriptions, learn, repeat daily. Until you master electronics. It's like learning and mastering anything. Practice Makes Better.

Comment: I am unable to understand your comment. can you please explain clearly one more time. tried and failed